# MobileFirst 8 UserAuthenticationSecurityCheck javascript class

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

we have working MobileFirst 6.3 javascript adapters on our app and authentication is based on the setActiveUser and getActiveUser of the WL.Server APIs.

Which is the equivalent in MobileFirst 8? I see that there is the UserAuthenticationSecurityCheck, but available only on java Adapters..

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In MobileFirst Foundation 8.0 authentication flows are implemented using security checks, and security checks are only Java adapters. There is no equivalent for this in JavaScript adapters for v8.0.

I recommend that you will read through the following topics to learn more about migrating to v8.0:

- Authentication and security: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/authentication-and-security/
- Migrating applications: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/upgrading/

Comment: So we should rewrite all our javascript adapters to java code??
Our adapters are all based on sessions, supported in MobileFirst 6.3 for example